# Applying an ARIMA model with exogenous variables for forecasting

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am using R, with the `forecast` package to forecast electricity generation from a wind farm with rain as exogenous variables.

I have estimated an ARIMA (1,0,1) Model with following function:

```
ModeloX3 <- arima(carg2, order=c(1,0,1), xreg=chuv, 
                  seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,0), period=NA))
```

where `carg2` is generation and `chuv` is rain.

My question is how to provide values of rain when forecasting generation:

```
fcast <- forecast(carg, h=5, xreg=chuv)
```

I know that I have to input 5 values of rain, but I do not know how to do this. Suppose rain in the next 5 periods is `2, 1, 3, 5, 6`, how can I input this in my model? I tried:

```
fcast <- forecast(carg, h=5, xreg=chuv(2,1,3,5,6))), but it did not work.
```

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Once the model has been trained (in this instance ModeloX3) you can produce forecasts with the forecast function. I think you are missing some understanding as to how ARMAX models work. It simply adds the `xreg` value as a covariate to the RHS of the equation, [see here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). This means the value needs to be explicitly provided for every time period you are trying to forecast for.

Your programming issue here can be solved by using the following template:

```
ModeloX3 <- arima(carg2, order=c(1,0,1), xreg=chuv, 
                  seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,0), period=NA))

chuvNext5 <- forecast(chuv, h = 5) #Vector containing the next 5 values of chuv time series. It is up to you how you make this, This is just a quick example.

fcast <- forecast(ModeloX3 , h=5, xreg=chuvNext5 ))
```